# I am using Custom fields plugin but I do not see Repeater field in that

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using custom fields plugin in my wordpress, but I am not able to see repeater field when I add a new field in and "Field Group".

I want to allow admin to upload multiple images (any number of images) from wp admin panel.

how can I do that?

Comment: To add repeater fields you need to buy the Pro version of the plugin. Read more here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/

Comment: There is addon available for repeater field in Advanced custom field plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeater field does not come by default with free version of ACF plugin. You need to upgrade to the pro version.

Ypu can get the pro version from here:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/

**Solution without repeater field:**

If you want to do this without using the repeater plugin then create a custom post type(using [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)) with name say 'customimage' and loop through them using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

LEARN MORE:

About custom post type

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/

About  ACF Repeater Field:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zc-HtIh7hE

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: I am not much in WP, so do you have any sample code or any blog URL where I can see this or a youtube video ?

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/ this post will help you on how to create a custom post type and use them on your site.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zc-HtIh7hE This video will help you learn how to set up acf repeater field and use it on your site.